# Explanation for rejection reason: level of establishment

Tags: canada, student-visa, refusal

I applied for a Canada study visa last month but after some time I got a refusal on the basis of following reasons:

1. level of establishment
2. language
3. financial ability
4. you are not genuine student

Please tell what should I write for **level of establishment** reason. Please give me a positive response as soon as possible.

Comment: Welcome to Expatriates! I fixed the formatting for you. Please don't use all-caps in the future--people think it looks like you're shouting, and it's harder to read. You may want to take the [tour].

Comment: "Level of establishment" might mean the examiner thought the school was inappropriate (either too advanced, or too basic, or too expensive) to plausibly comport with your own circumstances, study history, or finances.

Comment: ‘Level of establishment’ could mean that the institution you’re applying to is not on the approved list https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/study-canada/study-permit/prepare/designated-learning-institutions-list.html

Comment: Or maybe you could try [google](https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/what-is-level-of-establishment.351283/). It (apparently) means how established the applicant is in his home country, e.g. owns property, parents have good jobs etc.